# Passing a variable out of local functions

Tags: matlab

I'm having some trouble with local functions within my code so I've pasted a simple example below:

```
function [avg,testvar] = test(x)     %Warning
n = length(x);
avg = mymean(x,n);
end

function [a,testvar] = mymean(v,n)
a = sum(v)/n;
testvar=123;
end
```

One can probably see what I'm attempting; to pass `testvar` out of the local functions. However Matlab returns the warning:

```
"The function return value 'testvar' might be unset"
```

with respect to the line I've commented "%Warning".

What's the best way of getting around this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the value of the second output of test(). Otherwise how can MATLAB know what its value is supposed to be? It doesn't know the second output of mymean() should be routed to the second output of test(). Perhaps this will solve your problem.

```
function [avg,testvar] = test(x)     %Warning
  n = length(x);
  [avg, testvar] = mymean(x,n);
end

function [a,testvar] = mymean(v,n)
  a = sum(v)/n;
  testvar=123;
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. This should solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The variables between brackets after `function` are the output variables.

In your first function, you did not assign any value to `testvar` hence the warning. If you add `testvar = 123;` in the first function, the warning goes away. Or you can remove `testvar` from the output variables, leaving:

```
function avg = test(x)
```